# The onNewIntent method is not getting invoked

Tags: android

I am trying to create a twitter client and I am stuck with this scenario. There is a button in the Welcome screen which tells user to authorize the app. This button will call the twitter authorization page and returns a URL. I need to invoke the onNewIntent method to capture the URL details and store it. For some reason the method is not getting invoked. Please help.

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

is also not working.

**onCreate method**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    //Enabling strict mode
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    //get the preferences for the app
    nicePrefs = getSharedPreferences("WolfyPref", 0);


    //find out if the user preferences are set
    if(nicePrefs.getString("user_token", null)==null) {

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //no user preferences so prompt to sign in

        niceTwitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        niceTwitter.setOAuthConsumer(TWIT_KEY,TWIT_SECRET);
        //try to get request token
        try
        {
            //get authentication request token
            niceRequestToken = niceTwitter.getOAuthRequestToken(TWIT_URL);
        }
        catch(TwitterException te) { Log.e(LOG_TAG, "TE " + te.getMessage()); }

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    else
    {
        //user preferences are set - get timeline
        setupTimeline();
    }


/*    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);*/


}
```

**onClick**

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    //find view
    switch(v.getId()) {
        //sign in button pressed
        case R.id.fab:
            //take user to twitter authentication web page to allow app access to their twitter account
            String authURL = niceRequestToken.getAuthenticationURL();
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(authURL)));
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

**onNewIntent**

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    //get the retrieved data
    Uri twitURI = intent.getData();
    //make sure the url is correct
    if(twitURI!=null && twitURI.toString().startsWith(TWIT_URL))
    {
        //is verifcation - get the returned data
        String oaVerifier = twitURI.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");
        //attempt to retrieve access token
        try
        {
            //try to get an access token using the returned data from the verification page
            AccessToken accToken = niceTwitter.getOAuthAccessToken(niceRequestToken, oaVerifier);

            //add the token and secret to shared prefs for future reference
            nicePrefs.edit()
                    .putString("user_token", accToken.getToken())
                    .putString("user_secret", accToken.getTokenSecret())
                    .apply();

            //display the timeline
            setupTimeline();
        }
        catch (TwitterException te)
        { Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Failed to get access token: " + te.getMessage()); }

    }
}
```

Since the onNewIntent method is not getting invoked I am getting this screen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`onNewIntent` will be invoked for Activity with flag 'singleTop' only if this activity already exists in top of backstack. In your case you starting your Activity first time, so no invokation of `onNewIntent`.

See [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html#TaskLaunchModes) for more information.

Comment: If you have WelcomeActivity and AuthorizeActivity, just start second with intent and pass all data through 'extras'. Then in second activity in onCreate method retrieve extras and do whatever you want.

Comment: The same code was working fine before. I did something and it is not working anymore. I cannot add any more class files. Have to work on the same code.